# How to create a custom document library for videos in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: video, sharepoint-2010, shared-libraries

Can anybody explain create a custom document library for videos of types wmv, avi, mp4, flv etc. I am new in sharepoint , and i have one requirement for creating the same. Please help me if anybody has any idea about this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Site Actions and choose More Options. Choose Library then Asset Library. This will create a library for you but I am not sure if it will be restricted only to the file types you mentioned.